# Raphael.js: Why is the SVG positioned -0.5px to the left?

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

A feature of the web app I'm working on allows the replacement of an image inside a DIV with an exact replica as an SVG. This is done using the Raphael.js library.

Bellow is an example of such an HTML element containing an image:

```
<div id="ow-0" reference="0" class="object-wrapper" style="z-index: 3; width: 231px; left: 116px; top: 217px; outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) solid 1px; ">
    <img id="o-0" reference="0" class="object image" src="image-gallery/intermediate/3295094303_2b50e5fe03_z.jpg" />
</div>
```

When calling a method named `addSVG()`, the image parent `div` is set as the Raphael object `paper`, and the SVG with the image added to it, after the original image is hidden:

```
            // Create the SVG and add it to the Viewport
            this.addSVG = function(){

                // Hide the HTML element before replacing it with the SVG
                $("#o-"+this.ref).hide();

                // Create the "paper" (svg canvas) before embedding the actual SVG
                this.canvas = new Raphael(document.getElementById("ow-"+this.ref), this.width, this.height);                

                if (this.type=="image" || this.type=="QR"){
                    this.svg = this.canvas.image(this.src,0,0,this.width,this.height);

                }
                else {

                }
            }
```

Almost everything is perfect, with the exception of the positioning of the svg, which is -0.5px to the left (and this is annoyingly visible, of course). Bellow is the HTML code resulting after the operation:

```
    <div id="ow-0" reference="0" class="object-wrapper" style="z-index: 3; width: 231px; left: 116px; top: 217px; outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) solid 1px; ">
        <svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.5px; " height="170" version="1.1" width="231" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); ">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>
            <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); "></defs>
            <image style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " x="0" y="0" width="231" height="170" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="image-gallery/intermediate/3295094303_2b50e5fe03_z.jpg"></image>
        </svg>
        <img id="o-0" reference="0" class="object image" src="image-gallery/intermediate/3295094303_2b50e5fe03_z.jpg" style="display: none; ">
    </div>
```

Why is that -0.5px added and how can I prevent it from happening?
By the way, I resized the browser window, as an experiment, and that -0.5px was no longer added...

Comment: Doesn't seem to reproduce in Chrome, see http://jsfiddle.net/Xe88g/33/

Comment: In your HTML, would the offset of any of the parent elements be the result of a relative computation -- i.e., margin-left: 10%?  I've heard reports of this occurring where parent elements inherit fractional offsets from their environment.  Also: have you tried explicitly modifying Raphael's paper element after it is created, to set style:left to 0?

Comment: No, the position of the SVG inside its parent DOM element is absolute. Using CSS to explicitly style the SVG (top and left = 0) is the solution I found to solve the problem too in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution I have found to solve this problem is to explicitly set the `top` and `left` attributes (using CSS) of the SVG to 0, and mark the CSS rules as `!important`.

```
svg {
   top: 0 !important;
   left: 0 !important;
}
```

However, the reason of the problem is still unknown to me so if anyone has an answer, please share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Paper.renderfix() in order to fix this issue in IE9 and Firefox.

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.renderfix

> Paper.renderfix()
>
> Fixes the issue of Firefox and IE9 regarding subpixel rendering. If
>   paper is dependant on other elements after reflow it could shift half
>   pixel which cause for lines to lost their crispness. This method fixes
>   the issue.